# Иногда зависает база sqlite при выполнении запроса

Tags: java, sqlite

При выполнении запроса иногда база зависает. Я думаю, накосячил с потоками, но не могу понять где.

```java
    public static ResultSet UseUserScript(File fileEntry)
    {
        send(new Script(fileEntry).getCode());

        return results.remove(Thread.currentThread());
    }

    private static void send(String script)
    {
        MarkedStatement st = new MarkedStatement();
        st.script = script;
        st.Thread = Thread.currentThread();
        queue.add(st);
        synchronized (IOThread)
        {
            IOThread.notify();
        }

        synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
        {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().wait();//Зависание обычно происходит в этой строке
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isOnline)
        {

            if (queue.size() > 0)
            {
                try {
                    MarkedStatement st = queue.remove();
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    statement.execute(st.script);

                    results.put(st.Thread, statement.getResultSet());
                    synchronized (st.Thread)
                    {
                        st.Thread.notify();
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().wait();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за неправильного использования wait/notify.

В данной программе возможно такое выполнение, при котором `notify` будет послан, когда когда поток получатель уведомления, еще не выполнил `wait`, а значит после выполнения `wait` поток будет ждать вечно, т.к. новое уведомление никто больше не пошлет.

Главная проблема в программе это то, что сначала происходит добавление `MarkedStatement` в очередь, и только потом поток начинает ждать уведомления.

Может случится, что элемент из очереди будет обработан до того как поток начнет ждать уведомления.

Например, если непосредственно перед этим блоком синхронизации:

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
{
     try {
         Thread.currentThread().wait();//Зависание обычно происходит в этой строке
     } ...
```

произойдет переключения контекста и управление получит поток, в котором выполняется `run`. Если за время до следующего переключения контекста этот поток успеет выполнить запрос и послать уведомление с помощью `notify`, то первый поток, никогда это уведомление не получит.

Чтобы этого не случилось, добавлять задачу в очередь и посылать об этом уведомление, нужно в блоке синхронизации, который делает `wait`. Это даст гарантию, что поток посылающий `notify` не сможет это сделать до тех пор пока поток ждущий уведомление не вызовет `wait` (т.к. для вызова `notify` нужно захватить монитор, а он не будет доступен, пока не произойдет вызов `wait`, который собственно и отпускает монитор).

Вообще, wait/notify сложно использовать правильно именно из того, что нужно делать точную синхронизацию времени посылки и приема уведомления. Гораздо проще и надежнее использовать более высокоуровневые примитивы синхронизации.

В этом случае хорошо подошел бы `CountDownLatch`. Его первое (и главное в этом конкретном случае) преимущество, что для он помнит состояние, и не важно когда посылающий поток сделал уведомление. Даже если оно было послано до того, как получатель начал слушать, получатель все равно сможет узнать было ли уведомление:

```
private static void send(String script)
    {
        MarkedStatement st = new MarkedStatement();
        st.script = script;
        st.resultReadySignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        queue.add(st);
        synchronized (IOThread)
        {
            IOThread.notify();
        }

        st.resultReadySignal.await();
        return;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isOnline)
        {

            if (queue.size() > 0)
            {
                try {
                    MarkedStatement st = queue.remove();
                    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                    statement.execute(st.script);
                    results.put(st.Thread, statement.getResultSet());
                    st.resultReadySignal.countDown();
                }
                catch (SQLException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().wait();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Еще одно замечание.
В этом примере я только изменил, то что касается конкретно этой проблемы. Еще могут быть похожие сложности з уведомлением которое посылается, чтоб рабочий поток начал обработку задачи из очереди. Тут опять же лучше использовать более высокоуровневый класс для очереди [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).